# Fix a warning of ImageLoader : "Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before"

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

In my app, i have a listview with some items. Each item has a img which is downloaded from distant url.

I use ImageLoader library to load each image into my app.

My listview is well built, i have all images, but i have a warning in LogCat :

> 02-05 15:16:17.938: W/ImageLoader(17363): Try to initialize
>   ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. To re-init
>   ImageLoader with new configuration call ImageLoader.destroy() at
>   first.

I don't know how to fix this issue ?

Here the code of my adapter :

```
public class ArticleListAdapterHome extends ArrayAdapter<ArticleHome> {

    Typeface faceLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    Typeface faceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");

    public ArticleListAdapterHome(Activity activity, List<ArticleHome> articles) {
        super(activity, 0, articles);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        View rowView;
        ArticleHome article = getItem(position);

        if (position == 0) {

            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ligne_home_premier, null);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///// IMAGE
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ImageView imgfirst = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgimg) ;

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config); 
            imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImage(), imgfirst);

            ListView listV = (ListView)parent;
            boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
            boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
            PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
            listV.setOnScrollListener(listener);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///// TITLE
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titlepremier);     
            textView.setText(article.getTitle());
            textView.setTypeface(faceLight);
        }
        else {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ligne_home, null);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///// IMAGE
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgimg) ;

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config); 
            imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImage(), img);

            ListView listV = (ListView)parent;
            boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
            boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
            PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
            listV.setOnScrollListener(listener);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///// TITLE
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titlearticleothers);  
            title.setText(article.getTitle());
            title.setTypeface(faceBold);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///// DESCRIPTION
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            TextView desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionarticleothers);
            desc.setText(article.getDescription());
            desc.setTypeface(faceLight);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///// DATE
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            String pubDate = article.getPubDate();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date pDate;
            try {
                pDate = df.parse(pubDate);
                pubDate = DateUtils.getDateDifference(pDate);
                pubDate = pubDate.replace("-", "");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("DATE PARSING", "Error parsing date..");
                pubDate = "published by " + article.getAuthor();
            }
            date.setText("Il y a " +pubDate);

        }

        return rowView;

    }
```

Comment: add a comment to your code that shows where the error comes up

Answer (score 15):

This error occurs when you are trying to initialize ImageLoader when it is already initialized.

In my app I initialized ImageLoader two ways in different activities:

1:

```
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this.getSherlockActivity()));
```

2:

```
initImageLoader(); //where this function contained the configuration settings.
```

In my app I am using a `ViewPager` which causes this error and this is why:

It's important to know that when you open a tab in the `ViewPager` it automatically loads the second tab in the background.

Let's say this initialization was set on the first tab. So when you go to the second and the third tab then you go back to the second tab then the first one is loaded and it tries to initialize ImageLoader again.

***What you need to do is check if it was initialized***

```
if (!imageLoader.isInited()) {
    initImageLoader();
 }
```

Comment: would just applying this if loop the error will be resolve, or should I need to do something else also?

Answer (score 6):

ImageLoader must be initializated only once. You initializate every time when getView() method is called. It's could be better initializate imageLoder in your class extended from application

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ContextHolder.context = getApplicationContext();

        // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this configuration
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(5 * 1024 * 1024)) // 5 Mb (delete most not used image)
        .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
}
```

Your adapter after that

```
public class ArticleListAdapterHome extends ArrayAdapter<ArticleHome> {

Typeface faceLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
Typeface faceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public ArticleListAdapterHome(Activity activity, List<ArticleHome> articles) {
    super(activity, 0, articles);
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    View rowView;
    ArticleHome article = getItem(position);

    if (position == 0) {

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ligne_home_premier, null);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// IMAGE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ImageView imgfirst = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgimg) ;

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();

        imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImage(), imgfirst);

        ListView listV = (ListView)parent;
        boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
        boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
        PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
        listV.setOnScrollListener(listener);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// TITLE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titlepremier);     
        textView.setText(article.getTitle());
        textView.setTypeface(faceLight);
    }
    else {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ligne_home, null);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// IMAGE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgimg) ;

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
        .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
        .build();

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config); 
        imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImage(), img);

        ListView listV = (ListView)parent;
        boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
        boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
        PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
        listV.setOnScrollListener(listener);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// TITLE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titlearticleothers);  
        title.setText(article.getTitle());
        title.setTypeface(faceBold);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// DESCRIPTION
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionarticleothers);
        desc.setText(article.getDescription());
        desc.setTypeface(faceLight);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// DATE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        String pubDate = article.getPubDate();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date pDate;
        try {
            pDate = df.parse(pubDate);
            pubDate = DateUtils.getDateDifference(pDate);
            pubDate = pubDate.replace("-", "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("DATE PARSING", "Error parsing date..");
            pubDate = "published by " + article.getAuthor();
        }
        date.setText("Il y a " +pubDate);

    }

    return rowView;

}
```

Comment: Ok, so i must do this into the constructor of ArticleListAdapterHome ?

Comment: No, you should create class MyApp (for example) and extended it from Application (how in code above).  And also add android:name=".MyApp in    application section in manifest

Comment: What is ContextHolder is your example ?

Comment: Yes.  I called this class "ContextHolder" (i edit my answer to MyApp already), but it does't matter how you called it.

Comment: And after that, how must i replace my existing code in my adapter to have the global reference to the imageLoader instance ?

Comment: You might just delete imageLoader.init(config);   But will better make  imageLoder as field of class and initializate it in constructor ("imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance()")

Answer (score 0):

There something wrong with your adapter. Just a try:

```
public class ArticleListAdapterHome extends ArrayAdapter<ArticleHome> {

private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

Typeface faceLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
Typeface faceBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");

public ArticleListAdapterHome(Activity activity, List<ArticleHome> articles) {
    activity = a;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView;
    ArticleHome article = getItem(position);

    if (position == 0) {

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ligne_home_premier, null);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// IMAGE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ImageView imgfirst = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgimg) ;
        imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImage(), imgfirst);

        ListView listV = (ListView)parent;
        boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
        boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
        PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
        listV.setOnScrollListener(listener);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// TITLE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titlepremier);     
        textView.setText(article.getTitle());
        textView.setTypeface(faceLight);
    }
    else {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_ligne_home, null);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// IMAGE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ImageView img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgimg) ;

        imageLoader.displayImage(article.getImage(), img);

        ListView listV = (ListView)parent;
        boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
        boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
        PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
        listV.setOnScrollListener(listener);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// TITLE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titlearticleothers);  
        title.setText(article.getTitle());
        title.setTypeface(faceBold);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// DESCRIPTION
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView desc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionarticleothers);
        desc.setText(article.getDescription());
        desc.setTypeface(faceLight);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// DATE
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        String pubDate = article.getPubDate();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date pDate;
        try {
            pDate = df.parse(pubDate);
            pubDate = DateUtils.getDateDifference(pDate);
            pubDate = pubDate.replace("-", "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("DATE PARSING", "Error parsing date..");
            pubDate = "published by " + article.getAuthor();
        }
        date.setText("Il y a " +pubDate);

    }

    return rowView;

}
```

Dear user, you need to refer this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
Check how custom adapter is implemented..