# Fix warning of Universal Image Loader: "Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. Universal image loader"

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

My logcat gives me this message whenever I load an image in my application.

```
04-09 19:09:59.241: W/ImageLoader(276): 
Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before. 
To re-init ImageLoader with new configuration call ImageLoader.destroy() at first.
```

I do not understand why. Here is my code:

```
//If save on disk setting is false, do not save on disk. else, save on disk.
    if (dataReturned =="false"){
        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(false)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();
    }else{
        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();
    }
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); // Do it on Application start
```

This is someone else with the same problem, but it did not help me [Fix a warning of ImageLoader : "Try to initialize ImageLoader which had already been initialized before"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579826/fix-a-warning-of-imageloader-try-to-initialize-imageloader-which-had-already) since I do only initialize the ImageLoader onCreate, only once. While he initialized it over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have it on a Activity.

if you are going to put it in there, you would have to call ImageLoader.destroy on onDestroy like this:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    ImageLoader.getInstance().destroy();
}
```

You could put the initialization in your Application Class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html
something like this:

```
YourApplication extends Application {
    protected void onCreate() {
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but then I get:

    "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method destroy() from the type ImageLoader"

Comment: Oh right I can use ImageLoader.getInstance.destroy(); , dumb of me, thank you very much for the thinking help!